# Registering user through form in wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have a wordpress/woocommerce site that is completed except for one issue. My current form for wholesale customer registration is set to email me their info so that I can approve them as a wholesaler. This is fine but I see where a lot of form builders have add ons to register the user immediately when the form is submitted. I want to find a way to code that process so that when they submit my form it creates them as a base role or no role wordpress user automatically. I assume this can be done with some PHP function or a hook in wordpress

Comment: Could you provide some code/screenshots/anything?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is actually a google question... literally if you google "wp create user" you will get the finished code...

```
<?php
// Form submitted?
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $username = $_POST['username']; // add sanitize
  $password = $_POST['password']; // or generate using wp functions -> google
  $user = wp_create_user($username, $password, 'thatuseremail@gmail.com');

  // Update user role (if needed)
  wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user, 'role' => 'administrator'));
}
```